# Where and how can I upgrade my ipod 1st gen?

Tags: ipod-touch

How can I upgrade my ipod from version 1.1.5 (4B1), to a iOS5 on a 8gb pod?? I have no problem paying the $$ to have it upgraded.

Comment: The hardware doesn't have the oomph to run it.

Comment: Or in other words: The upgrade will cost you $199 (or more) and Apple will be generous and give you new hardware for free :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Your model does not support iOS 5. No amount of money will help you here.